# Problem when trying to generate Allure report using RobotFramework

Tags: report, robotframework, allure

Settings:

Windows 10 (64 Bits)

Installed the library below:

`pip install allure-robotframework`

Librarys (pip list):

pip list

```
-------------------------------------- --------
allure-python-commons                  2.13.2
allure-robotframework                  2.13.2
Appium-Python-Client                   1.3.0
async-generator                        1.10
attrs                                  23.1.0
certifi                                2023.5.7
cffi                                   1.15.1
charset-normalizer                     3.1.0
decorator                              5.1.1
docutils                               0.20
exceptiongroup                         1.1.1
h11                                    0.14.0
idna                                   3.4
importlib-metadata                     6.6.0
kitchen                                1.2.6
natsort                                8.3.1
numpy                                  1.24.3
outcome                                1.2.0
pandas                                 2.0.1
pip                                    22.3.1
pluggy                                 1.0.0
psutil                                 5.9.4
PySocks                                1.7.1
python-dateutil                        2.8.2
pytz                                   2023.3
requests                               2.28.2
robotframework                         6.0.2
robotframework-appiumlibrary           1.6.4
robotframework-applicationlibrary      1.1.2
robotframework-pythonlibcore           4.1.2
robotframework-requests                0.9.4
robotframework-seleniumlibrary         6.0.0
robotframework-stacktrace              0.4.1
robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1.4
selenium                               3.141.0
setuptools                             65.5.0
six                                    1.16.0
sniffio                                1.3.0
sortedcontainers                       2.4.0
suds-bis                               1.0.0
trio                                   0.22.0
trio-websocket                         0.10.2
tzdata                                 2023.3
urllib3                                1.26.15
wsproto                                1.2.0
zipp                                   3.15.0
```

Command Line:

`robot --listener allure_robotframework myTest.robot`

Generated report:

[image]

What am I doing wrong for the report not to be generated correctly in the Allure form.

I really didn't find much on the internet about this subject, but what I found was trying to run the command "allure serve ./'path to data generated(folder containing json, html files)'.", but I got the following message:

"allure : The term 'allure' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program name. Check the spelling of the name or, if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again."